# I know that I can add an icon to my page title but is it possible to add multiple icons on either side of the page title?

Tags: html

So the following code adds an icon to the left side of my title like all other usual pages on the web but is it possible to add the icon on either side of the page title? what about multiple icons?

`<head>
    <title>CodingSilence</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="skull.ico" />
</head>`

Comment: it's known as a favicon :)

Comment: I'd never considered this, but I think the answer is 'no'; I'd be interested to find out if I'm wrong though. :)

Comment: No. The favicon is not a part of the title. You can add emojis but not custom icons 

Comment: Firefox supports gif favicon, so you can animate changing from one to another :)

Comment: This is totally pointless, you should focus on the website's content and usability

Comment: Nice to know other people are curious about this aspect too. Thank you.
@AlonEitan just because im curious about something doesnt mean im not focusing on the important details. Your answer was pointless to this question.

Comment: @RiyazM Yes it's totally fine and your question is fine too, I just think that in general perspective this type of feature is not important, to say the least

Comment: @RiyazM But if you want you can try [this website](http://shapecatcher.com/) that try to recognise a saphe and show you its alternative as a UTF-8 char code that you can then copy and paste in your website `<title>` tag